# Redis server port already in use

Tags: redis

I'm using Redis version 2.2.13

```
jack@ubuntu:~/redis$ src/redis-server
[23900] 14 Sep 14:28:52 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use 'redis-server /path/to/redis.conf'
[23900] 14 Sep 14:28:52 # Opening port: bind: Address already in use
```

So I follow the above instructions and try

```
redis-server $HOME/redis/redis.conf
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
*** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR ***
Reading the configuration file, at line 135
>>> 'slave-serve-stale-data yes'
Bad directive or wrong number of arguments
```

The file has the following comments:

```
# When a slave lost the connection with the master, or when the replication
# is still in progress, the slave can act in two different ways:
#
# 1) if slave-serve-stale-data is set to 'yes' (the default) the slave will
#    still reply to client requests, possibly with out of data data, or the
#    data set may just be empty if this is the first synchronization.
#
# 2) if slave-serve-stale data is set to 'no' the slave will reply with
#    an error "SYNC with master in progress" to all the kind of commands
#    but to INFO and SLAVEOF.
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: version 2.2.13, I think i've solved the problem now!
I used the following, to make sure I was running the correct file:
$HOME/redis/src/redis-server $HOME/redis/redis.conf

Answer (score 107, accepted):

I had this same problem, but I forgot that redis persists.  If you get this error, try this command:

```
redis-cli ping
```

if you get PONG as a response, then Redis is running, and the port is in use, by Redis.

Answer (score 60):

And after running `redis-cli ping` and getting a positive response, simply run `redis-cli shutdown`

Comment: Its giving me error -  (error) ERR Errors trying to SHUTDOWN. Check logs.

Answer (score 13):

Try searching for redis folder on your machine, in my case, I had redis-server running in another application. Switch to that directory and run:

```
redis-cli ping
```

If it returns PONG, run:

```
redis-cli shutdown
```

This should shut down the redis, and now go to your project and try running:

```
redis-server
```

Answer (score 10):

There must be another version of redis server installed on my machine, I ran it using the following command:

```
$HOME/redis/src/redis-server $HOME/redis/redis.conf
```

Everything seems to be working.

Comment: /root/redis/src/redis-server: No such file or directory

Answer (score 2):

try use another port and set it daemonize

`./redis-server --port 6379 --daemonize yes`